# Input field width unaffected by margin

Tags: html, css

I've got a really simple problem. Input element types are not affected by margin as expected. I'm guessing that input has some kind of default styling going on that is making it behave unexpectedly.

The expected result is that when I apply a margin of 5 pixels, the input field has a 5 pixel buffer completely surrounding it. What happens instead is that it has a 5 pixel buffer on the top, left, and bottom, but not the right.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.width-50 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.margin-10px {
  margin: 10px;
}

.padding-10px {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-100">
  <div class="width-50">
    <input class="margin-10px" value="This input should be filling in all the way to the right"></input>
  </div>
  <!--
       -->
  <div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div>
  <!--
      -->
  <div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div>
  <!--
      -->
  <div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ar7z0ky8/2/)

Comment: I am sorry, but the issue that you have mentioned is about margin only right, because its a bit unclear, but I can see that the margin exactly 10px. Check this [here](https://snag.gy/9An1ra.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **border-box** and **calc** because width not include `padding` and `margin` without it

`border-box` : The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin... Note that padding and border will be inside of the box. and need to include margin you need to subtract it from `width:100%` using `width:calc(100% - 20px);`

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.wd100{
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.width-50 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.margin-10px {
  margin: 10px;
}

.padding-10px {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-100">
  <div class="width-50">
    <input class="margin-10px padding-10px wd100" value="This input should be filling in all the way to the right"/>
  </div><!--
   --><div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px wd100">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px wd100">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px wd100">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` is not 100% wide, it is getting the default value from the browser.

Try:

```
input {
 width: 100%;
 ...
}
```

Or you can use your own classes to to it:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.width-50 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.margin-10px {
  margin: 10px;
}

.padding-10px {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-100">
  <div class="width-50 padding-10px">
    <input class="padding-10px" value="This input should be filling in all the way to the right"></input>
  </div><div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div><div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div><div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then the result is that the right edge of the input field extends beyond its container by the margin amount.

Comment: I see... This margin on your `input` behaves a little bit weird, to solve this you can set the padding on the input's parent element and remove the margin from your `input`... see updated answer... Also I recommend you to use `box-sizing` on your elements.

Comment: So using the CSS Box Model is not possible on inputs? To add a margin around my inputs, I have to wrap every single one of them with a div and apply padding to that div?

Comment: 1- It is possible, but box-sizing do not calculate the margin. 2 - If you do not want to apply the `calc()` (`width: calc(100% - 20px);`) method to your inputs, yes you will need to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `width` and `height` of the *input-field*. Try this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
input {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
}
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.width-50 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
.margin-10px {
  margin: 10px;
}
.padding-10px {
  padding: 10px;
}

/* added CSS */
input {
  width: 90%;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-100">
  <div class="width-50">
    <input class="margin-10px padding-10px" value="This input should be filling in all the way to the right">
  </div>
  <div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="width-50">
    <div class="margin-10px padding-10px">This div is filling in the space as expected.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```